# Selecting the complement of distinct triples in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have tables like these two

```
test_table
date        student     test
2012-05-31  Alice       Math
2012-05-31  Alice       Math
2012-05-31  Bob         Math
2012-05-31  Bob         Spelling
2012-06-01  Alice       Math
2012-06-01  Alice       Spelling

score_table
date        student     test        best_daily_score
2012-05-31  Alice       Math        90
2012-05-31  Bob         Math        50
2012-05-31  Bob         Spelling    50
2012-06-01  Alice       Math        95
```

I'd like to detect that Alice's `best_daily_score` for the `Spelling` test on `2012-06-01` hasn't been recorded yet. I'm looking for the query that returns

```
2012-06-01  Alice       Spelling
```

which is the only row of

```
SELECT DISTINCT date, student, test FROM test_table
```

that is not in

```
SELECT DISTINCT date, student, test FROM score_table
```

This doesn't work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date, student, test FROM test_table WHERE date, student, test NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT date, student, test FROM score_table)
```

I assume because the left side of `NOT IN` should not be a list of three things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT  a.date,
        a.student,
        a.test
  FROM  test_table a 
          LEFT JOIN score_table b
            ON (a.date = b.date) AND
               (a.student = b.student) AND
               (a.test = b.test)
WHERE   b.best_daily_score IS NULL
```

The query tries to match all the records from `test_table` to `score_table` whether it exists or not because of the `LEFT JOIN`. It matches for `date`, `student`, and `test`. If the record was not found on `score_table`, so basically `best_daily_score` would be `NULL`. That's why I added a condition to show only `NULL` on `best_daily_score`.

**[Click Here for some DEMO (SQLFiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f81d/2)**